# Mix Flask/Jinja pagination with refresh of part of page content (div) only (not whole page)

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, flask, pagination, jinja2

Up to now I'm using Flask/Jinja pagination like example described [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ix-pagination) (see *Page navigation* chapter).
This works fine except now I need for some reasons my (main) page to **not be reloaded** when using pagination process (ie when clicking next/previous links). I'd like a single `<div>` to be modified (data is coming from a database via SQLAlchemy, not sure it is important).

Then I tested Ajax call to try to get some dynamic content in pages (like in [this example](https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/jqueryexample)). 
This works fine too for basic situations (loading a div etc...).

My problem is that up to now I'm unable to **mix both of them**, ie **flask/Jinja pagination + ajax dynamic refresh of a `<div>`**.
I've found a couple of close things on the web but not exactly this case (especially involving Flask/Jinja).

I was wondering if the cause could not be the fact the solution in 1st example involves to new call to route like below (`/index/<int:page>`) when clicking a "next/prev page" :

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index(page=1):
    form = PostForm()
    ...
```

Does anyone would have :

- a (complete/detailled) example on how to proceed with above stuff ?
- or an alternative solution for this ?

By the way I tested **Flask-paginate** as well. Unfortunately it seems reloading page like above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's been over a year, so that's probably no use for you, but I had the same problem and here's how I figured the same problem out. Maybe it will help someone.

I'll skip the core AJAX part and only describe how I figured out **mixing flask-sqlalchemy pagination with jquery AJAX calls**:

so let's say I had a route for index and results routes. I generate the index page from template, then add an event in a form to post data from input and then get the **html result** using jquery AJAX call with (not the typical JSON file)

now the problem is: **how to pass new page argument to the call?**

i figured out to: **include page number as query-string by url_for**, then **get an href attr** from page link using jquery and then **pass it to AJAX call url**

here is how key parts of code looks like after:

Jinja/HTML (only part responsible for results and page link generating):

```
          {% for result in results%}
                <div>{{ result.name }}</div
          {% endfor %}

          {% for page in restaurants.iter_pages() %}
                <a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('search_results', page=page) }}">{{ page }}</a>
          {% endfor %}
```

JQuery script (only part responsible for calling ajax from page-link):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(event) {

      var link = $(this).attr('href');
      searchResults(link);
      event.preventDefault();

  });
});

  var searchResults = function(link) {
      req=$.ajax({
        data : {
          parameter1: $('input[name="parameter1"]').val()
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: link

      });
      req.done(function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
      })
  };
```

Flask:

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainPage():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('_search_results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def searchResults():
    page = request.args.get('page')
    page = 1 if page == None else int(page)
    user_parameter = request.form['parameter1'].lower()
    results = Item.query.filter(Item.parameter == user_parameter).paginate(page=page)

    return render_template("results.html", results=results)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following to solve this problem:


In my python code..

1. I am extracting the items of the page using Pagination.items.

2. I am extracting the list of page numbers using Pagination.iter_pages(..)
And sending both as json response.

```
@app.route('/filter', defaults={'page_num':1}, methods=['get'])
@app.route('/filter/<int:page_num>', methods=['get'])
def filter(page_num):
    if request.method=='GET':
        filter_criteria = request.args.get("query")

        if filter_criteria != "":
            like_filter_criteria = "%" + filter_criteria + "%"
            search_results = db.session.query(Data).filter(or_(Data.mobile1.like(like_filter_criteria),
            Data.mobile2.like(like_filter_criteria),
            Data.mobile3.like(like_filter_criteria))).filter(and_(Data.active_status == "Y")).order_by(Data.name)
        else:
            search_results = fetch_all_details()

        if search_results != None:
            paginationObj = search_results.paginate(per_page=3,page=page_num,error_out=True)
            num_list = []
            for i in paginationObj.iter_pages(left_edge = 3, right_edge = 3, left_current = 3, right_current = 3):
                num_list.append(i)
            return jsonify({'json_list' : [i.serialize for i in paginationObj.items],
            'pages_lst' : num_list})
```

In my JavaScript..
1. I am accessing the value of items to be shown on each page normally

```
    function get_cust_data(pageNum){
      var formData = {'query': $('input[name=query]').val()}

        $.ajax({
            url: '/filter' + pageNum,
            data: formData,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                show_data_in_table(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }

    function show_data_in_table(response){
        var new_tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        new_tbody.setAttribute("id","tbody");
        var data = response['json_list'];
        var page_numbers = response['pages_lst'];

        var cust_data = '';
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
          cust_data += '<tr>';
          cust_data += '<td>' + value.name + '</td>';
          cust_data += '<td>' + value.mobile1 + '</td>';
          cust_data += '<td>' + value.mobile2 + '</td>';
          cust_data += '<td>' + value.mobile3 + '</td>';
          cust_data += '<td>' + value.address + '</td>';
          cust_data += '<td>' + '<a href='+ Flask.url_for('index',{'id':value.id, 'action':'edit'}) +'>Edit</a></td>';
          cust_data += '<td>' +
          '<form id="frm_delete" action="'+ Flask.url_for('delete_cust') +'" method="post" role="form">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="id_to_delete" id="id_to_delete" value="'+ value.id + '">' +
            '<a href="#" id="btn_delete">Delete</a>' +
          '</form>' + '</td>';
          cust_data += '</tr>';
        });
        new_tbody.innerHTML = cust_data;
        var old_tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
        old_tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(new_tbody, old_tbody);

        show_page_numbers(page_numbers);

    }
```

2. And accessing the list of page numbers the same way.

```
    function show_page_numbers(page_numbers){
      var new_links_box = document.createElement('div');
      new_links_box.setAttribute("id","paginationBox");

      var anchorTags = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < page_numbers.length; i++){
        var item = page_numbers[i] === null ? ellipsis : page_numbers[i] ;
        anchorTags += '<a href='+ Flask.url_for('filter') + ' id="page_num_link">'+ item +'</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
      }
      new_links_box.innerHTML = anchorTags;
      var old_links_box = document.getElementById('paginationBox');
      old_links_box.parentNode.replaceChild(new_links_box,old_links_box);
    }
```

Then I use some good old js to access the page number clicked by the user and send it to be used along with my ajax call which also gets called on page load.

```
$("#datalist").on("click","#paginationBox #page_num_link", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = '/' + $(e.target).html();
        if(page != ellipsis){
            get_cust_data(page);
        }
      });
```

And this is how my template looks like. It has nothing in it basically as everything is dynamic.

```
          <table id="body_tbl">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>mobile 1</th>
                <th>mobile 2</th>
                <th>mobile 3</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody id="tbody">
           </tbody>
          </table>

          <div id="paginationBox">
          </div>
```

With this the link click event doesn't load the page while the pagination functionality is working as its expected to work.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the following error when I run the code of this response: jquery.min.js:2          GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/filterundefined 404 (NOT FOUND)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
get_cust_data @ mama:153
(anonymous) @ mama:179
mama:161 {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

Comment: I do not seem to understand the " like_filter_criteria = "%" + filter_criteria + "% "  and how it is used in subsequent sections in the code. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this macro will work as a paginator

```
{% macro html(url_name, page_obj, url_param_name) %}
   <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
       <ul class="pagination">
        
           {% if page_obj.has_previous() %}
               <li class="page-item">
                   <a class="page-link" href="{{ url(url_name) }}?{{ url_param_name }}={{ page_obj.previous_page_number() }}">
                       Previous
                   </a>
               </li>
           {% endif %}
        

           {% if 1 < page_obj.number-5 %}
               <li class="page-item disabled">
                   <a class="page-link" href="#">
                       ...
                   </a>
               </li>
           {% endif %}

           {% for page in range(page_obj.number-5, page_obj.paginator.num_pages+1) %}

               {% if page > 0 and page <= page_obj.number+5 %}
                   <li class="page-item {% if page == page_obj.number %} active {% endif %}">
                       <a class="page-link" href="{{ url(url_name) }}?{{ url_param_name }}={{ page }}">
                           {{ page }}
                       </a>
                   </li>
               {% endif %}

           {% endfor %}

           {% if page_obj.number < page_obj.paginator.num_pages-5 %}
               <li class="page-item disabled">
                   <a class="page-link" href="#">
                       ...
                   </a>
               </li>
           {% endif %}


           {% if page_obj.has_next() %}
               <li class="page-item">
                   <a class="page-link" href="{{ url(url_name) }}?{{ url_param_name }}={{ page_obj.next_page_number() }}">
                       Next
                   </a>
               </li>
           {% endif %}
        
       </ul>
   </nav>

   <span class="page-current">
       Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
   </span>
{% endmacro %}
```